# Salesforce Data transfer Via Rest API

Tags: rest-api

I'm working with Salesforce Rest APIs, as we can get records to call this example endpoint
`https://mydomainname.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v55.0/sobjects/Account/001D000000INjVe`.

I want to get a record from the Account Object on the basis of the value in a specific column. Is that possible to get a record by passing the field API Name and Value? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Do you want to pass dynamic ID ?

Comment: Probably you want to use the `query` resource instead? eg. `/services/data/v55.0/query/?q=SELECT+name+from+Account+where+field=value`

Comment: @hengkyDjapar Thank you it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use arbitrary fields to retrieve a single record from the "sobjects" resource through the REST API.

Your options are [to use the record Id](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_retrieve_get.htm), or [use a field marked as an "external id"](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_upsert_get.htm). I'm not sure what would happen if a single external Id were to be used on multiple records.

Beyond that, you would either need to create your own custom REST endpoint (using Apex) or [use the "query" resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_query.htm).

Comment: I have set the field as External Id that works.